# MySQL INSERT with a SELECT based on matching column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to populate a table's id's in one table based on some matching column in another table, here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO adverts (publication_id) VALUES (SELECT publications.id FROM publications WHERE publications.name LIKE CONCAT ('%', (adverts.publication), '%'));
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT publications.id FROM publications WHERE publications.name
>   LIKE CONCAT ('%' at line 1

Not sure where I am going wrong here, can anybody help?

Below are my 2 table structures:

Adverts table: 
[image]

Publications table:
[image]

**EDIT**
Below you can find some sample data from both tables, ideally what I am trying to achieve is to insert the `id` value from the `publications` table into the `publications_id` in the `adverts` table based on whether or not there is a match in the `advert.publication` - `publications.name` columns.

Adverts sample data:
[image]

Publications sample data:
[image]

Textual format of sample data:

Adverts:

```
"56d4085e-654c-47e1-86f0-1e7f5850bebe",,"Saturday 27th February 2016","The Daily Telegraph","188833f6-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","2016-09-06","pdf/1/a/1a5a83.pdf","0","2016-02-29 08:59:10","2016-09-06 08:31:50"
"56d71a59-60cc-4a9b-9170-0eb15850bebe",,"Sunday 28th February 2016","The Scottish Sunday Mail",,"2016-02-28","jpg/a/8/a8d73b.jpg","0","2016-03-02 16:52:41","2016-03-02 16:53:13"
"56daa0f6-a2c8-4346-ac05-6f825850bebe",,"Saturday 5th March 2016","The Daily Telegraph",,"2016-03-05","pdf/9/e/9eda94.pdf","0","2016-03-05 09:03:50","2016-03-05 09:04:59"
"56daa30b-f8c4-40aa-8197-6f555850bebe",,"Friday 12th February 2016","Daily Star",,"2016-02-12","pdf/9/2/921346.pdf","0","2016-03-05 09:12:43","2016-03-05 09:13:26"
"56daa37c-a46c-4446-9fa5-6f825850bebe",,"Sunday 14th February 2016","Sunday Express",,"2016-02-14","pdf/3/b/3b8fc2.pdf","0","2016-03-05 09:14:36","2016-03-05 09:14:36"
"56daa3ee-441c-4bb0-b9ff-6f555850bebe",,"Saturday 27th February 2016","Daily Express",,"2016-02-27","pdf/e/b/ebb99b.pdf","0","2016-03-05 09:16:30","2016-03-05 09:16:30"
"56daa44f-4124-41bd-bb34-6fb95850bebe",,"Sunday 28th February 2016","Daily Star Sunday ",,"2016-02-28","pdf/1/e/1e412d.pdf","0","2016-03-05 09:18:07","2016-03-05 09:18:07"
```

Publications:

```
"000f371a-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","The Daily Telegraph","png/6/9/69e409.png","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:43:31"
"10895d76-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","The Scottish Sunday Mail","jpg/4/1/41b6e6.jpg","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:44:02"
"188833f6-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","Daily Star","png/d/c/dcb8dd.png","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:44:22"
"212778a5-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","Sunday Express","gif/5/2/529a66.gif","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:45:57"
"2fa48a98-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","Daily Express","gif/6/c/6c5be4.gif","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:46:19"
"37d0b036-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","Daily Star Sunday","png/c/e/ce7c42.png","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:46:44"
"3f78db05-7405-11e6-96f3-0800274f2cef","Scottish Daily Mail","jpg/5/c/5caf2f.jpg","2016-09-06 00:00:00","2016-09-06 07:47:10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `UPDATE` not an `INSERT` statement:

```
UPDATE Adverts a
JOIN Publications p ON a.publication LIKE  CONCAT('%', (p.name), '%')
SET a.publication_id = p.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e852f/1)

Comment: Just tried this, now I'm getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'adverts.publication' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @user3574492 Ooops, my bad. You can't use `adverts` table in the `SELECT` part of the statement. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a bunch of publications that can have many adverts (adverts belong to a publication). I am trying to insert the publication id of the publication into the adverts table that the advert belongs to. if that makes sense?

Comment: In that case you need to `UPDATE` the `adverts` table, not `INSERT`. Can you share some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: @user3574492 Can you please add the sample data in textual format?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO adverts (publication_id) 
  SELECT publications.id 
  FROM publications join adverts  on <condition> 
  WHERE publications.name LIKE CONCAT ('%', (adverts.publication), '%'));
```